# How to keep button down on a ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon, ribbonx

I've got a custom ribbon tab in Excel. Is there any way to keep a custom toggle button pressed down?

I found an example in the `VIEW > Workbooks Views` section. One view can be selected and button is kept down.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **toggleButton** control and use the **getPressed** callback which allows to specify whether the toggle button control is pressed or not. You can read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thank you Eugene. Just mixed button and toggle button. All clear now.